# How to generate and respond with cookie at first request?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement browser like cookie/session feature into my game for login system.

As far as I understand here is How cookies work;

```
1 - Client request page without cookie in requestheader.
2 - Server receives requestheader without cookie in it and generates cookie for client.
3 - Server responds with a cookie for first request.
4 - In further requests server includes cookie in header.
5 - Client copies cookie info from second respond and adds it into requestheader later on.
```

The problem is, I need to be able to send cookie at first request because in unity3d in every request SessionId for my client changes.

It doesnt act like a browser unless I include cookie in requestheader which I dont have at first request. So It gets stuck in between 1-3 steps.

**UPDATE :** 
Here is my experience in Chrome with following codeigniter code.

```
public function getcookie()
{
    echo $this->input->get_request_header('Cookie', TRUE);
}
```

**When I call this page which is:
http://mydomainaddr.com/srv/index.php/Srv/getcookie
It doesnt print anything at first request.
When i refresh it starts printing...**

Comment: Isn't #3 the *second* request?  Something seems wrong there, that request should include the cookie.

Comment: Aparently your client application doesn't return the received cookie information, which leads the server to believe that it's a new client on each request... Your problems lie elsewhere...

Comment: Elaborate further on your intended usage. If you write the HTTP client yourself, nobody can stop you from inserting a client-generated and agreed-upon session/cookie id yourself. Just means standard browsers will be exempt from that shortcut.

Comment: The client's SessionID changes with each request... really? The whole point of sessions is not to change all the time.

Comment: I updated question and added actual code and what I experience without personal comment please check out :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would the server not respond with a cookie in `3`? Most sites will give you a session id right on the first visit. This is how I've always done it at least.

Actually, if you don't send a cookie on the first request, how do you know a visitor is on his second request?

Comment: I updated question and added actual code and what I experience without personal comment please check out :)

Answer (score 0):

At first respond server sends cookie information in SET-COOKIE or Set-Cookie header,(Not in Cookie header) in response headers which I should have later include in my request headers.

So that explains why there was no "Cookie" named header in first request.